# Creating object with type safety

Tags: java, thread-local

I'm using ThreadLocal for getting current logged in User into my application as

```
private static ThreadLocal<User> userAuditor = new ThreadLocal<>();
User user = Auditor.userAuditor.get();
```

Will it make any difference if I don't specify type at the right side while creating object like the one mentioned above

Or will I have to specify type while creating object like the one mentioned below:

```
private static ThreadLocal<User> userAuditor = new ThreadLocal<User>();
```

Comment: No. `<>` is a shorthand for whatever you specified on the left hand side.

Comment: When you assign to `ThreadLocal<User>` it's implicitly known what type the new instance has to get. Compiler will handle that for you.

Comment: Why are you using ThreadLocal? Are you going to override, `initialValue`?

Answer (score 1):

Since java 7 you could omit the Diamond operator **<>** at the right side when using generics, this feature was added only for code readability,**it is helpful when using nested collection types** and it doesn't affect the code logic or performance,thus it's up to your personal preferences.